# The svn status does not display the correct content

Tags: svn, command, tortoisesvn

There is a folder in the svn version library that contains three files. If I use the `svn update` command locally to update a file in this folder, then use the `svn status` command to check the status of the other two files.

```
E:\Test>svn status -u
        *            folder\file_03.cs
        *            folder\file_02.cs
        *            folder\file_01.cs
        *            folder
E:\Test>svn update --parents folder\file_01.cs
A    folder
Updating 'folder\file_01.cs':
A    folder\file_01.cs
E:\Test>svn status -u
Status against revision:    xxx
```

I hope to run `svn status -u` after `svn update --parents folder\file_01.cs` to display the status of `file_02` and `file_03`.

I tried using `svn status --no-ignore`, but it didn't work.

When I use `update to revision--Choose items` in folder, I can see that `file_02` and `file_03` are not checked. I don't know whether this is related to my problem. If so, I would like to know which command can be used in the command line to check these two files. And make them display the correct state under `svn update -u`.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce the behavior. It *is* surprising and there seems to be no way of ever getting `file_02` and `file_03` except `update`-ing them by name explicitly. If nobody comes up with a solution in reasonable time, I'd consider using Subversion's bug tracker.